# File Permissions Issue with Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight, file

I have a Silverlight 4 / C# project I'm working on in Visual Studio. I made an XML data file by right clicking on the project >> Add New Item >> Xml File. I then try to open the file:

```
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("data.xml");
```

However, this gives a security exception. How can I get around this, or grant the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor of StreamReader is expecting a file path into the local file system, which is only available out of browser with elevated trust.

Instead you should be using `Application.GetResourceStream`:-

```
Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("data.xml", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

However I expect you really just want this in an `XDocument`, you bypass this StreamReader stage:-

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

BTW, I personally would leave the XML as Content in the Xap rather than embedding it in the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need to be able to read the file at execution time? If so, I would suggest you set it to have a Resource build action in Visual Studio, and then use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to open it. That's the simplest way of bundling read-only data with an application, IMO.

Comment: see comment below, SL does not honor embedded resource reference based on MSDN

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight doesn't allow local file system access by default. Your options are:

- Using [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx).
- Run with [elevated permissions](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-elevated-permissions.aspx).
- Embedding the file in the assembly, if you only need to read it, [as suggested by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217917/file-permissions-issue-with-silverlight/4217952#4217952).

If you need to store data in general, use IsolatedStorage if you can.

Comment: -1 The OP is not intentionally trying to read from the local disk but as a resource instead so the IsolatedStorage and elevated permissions reference is not needed, in addition Skeet's post references making it an embedded resource which is not valid for SL

Answer (score 2):

You would need to mark the item as a **resource**, NOT an **embedded resource**.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28VS.95%29.aspx)...

> The Properties window in Visual Studio
>   provides several other values in the
>   Build Action drop-down list. However,
>   you can use only the previous three
>   values with Silverlight projects. In
>   particular, Silverlight embedded
>   resources must always use the Resource
>   build action, and not the Embedded
>   Resource build action, which uses a
>   format that Silverlight cannot
>   recognize.

A great walk through can be seen [here](http://www.xs4all.nl/~wrb/Articles/Article_SL_ResourceFiles_01.htm) entailing what you are trying to accomplish. Since you are not trying to access files on disk but as resources this is not a problem. IsolatedStorage nor elevated permissions are pertinent here.

Comment: Hmm... odd. It works in WP7, which s pretty much all the direct experience I have of SL. Is it still broken in SL4?

Comment: @Jon Have not tried in SL4 but other versions of SL...can only go off the docs at the moment...